# Django- process data passed through a template

Tags: python, django, post

I am creating a page which displays multiple choice questions with choices as radio buttons (and should show result to user on submitting, based on the choices they select). I am using the following model for the questions:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    q_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    q_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice4 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    correct_ans = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The view which displays the questions is :

```py
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('q_id')[:10]
    return render(request,'index.html',{'latest_question_list': latest_question_list})
```

and the template (index.html) is :

```html
<body>
  {% if latest_question_list %}
    <form action="/result/" method="post">
      <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}

             <li>{{ question.q_text }}</li>
             <input type="radio" name="{{question.q_id}}" value="1" />{{ question.choice1}}<br>
             <input type="radio" name="{{question.q_id}}" value="2" />{{ question.choice2}}<br>
             <input type="radio" name="{{question.q_id}}" value="3" />{{ question.choice3}}<br>
             <input type="radio" name="{{question.q_id}}" value="4" />{{ question.choice4}}<br>

        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <input style="margin-left:2%" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
   {% endif %}
</body>
```

I want to know what should I write in the 'result' view. 
That is, how do i check the selected choice by the user and match it with the correct question-choice pair stored in the Question model so as to display the score of the user in the 'result' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have number of questions, so in your results view, declare a dictionary and iterate like this,
`dict = {}
for i in numberOfQuestion:
    dict[i] = request.POST.get('questions.'+i) 
    #dict will have all answers with question numbers`

Answer (score 1):

Set in your urls.py

```
def yourView(request):
  q = request.GET.get('q')
  # note that 'q' is the value of the input
  # the logic goes here
```

so change your inputs -> `<input type="radio" name="q" value="1" />{{ question.choice1}}<br>`

Comment: But I want the 'name' attribute to be unique, otherwise i will be able to select the choice for only one question out of all the questions in the latest_question_list. If I pass the q_id in the name how can I get it back in the view ?